# Getting errors when training sphinxtrain

Tags: python, perl, speech-recognition, sphinx

I am trying to implement a sphinx model for a language.  But I am getting some errors when training the system.

The following command is used in cmd to train sphinx:

```
python ../sphinxtrain/scripts/sphinxtrain run
```

However, I get the following errors.

```
Can't open D:/sphinx/other/result/other-1-1.match
word_align.pl failed with error code -1 at D:/sphinx/sphinxtrain/scripts/decode/slave.pl line 173.
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J2IF4enp5aAC3GGBXORODukomr42q7qU/view?usp=sharing) is the file slave.pl:

And also these errors:

```
INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='batch', 
VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
ERROR: "acmod.c", line 79: Folder 'D:/sphinx/other/model_parameters/other.ci_cont' does not contain      
acoustic model definition 'mdef'
FATAL: "batch.c", line 913: PocketSphinx decoder init failed
```

The `sphinx>other>logdir>decode>other-1-1.log` is also blank.

Comment: The link to google drive for `slave.pl` does not work. I get "Access denied"

Comment: Always post everything the question needs. But, debugging hundreds of lines of some program isn't a good use of Stackoverflow.

Comment: @HåkonHægland, i have changed the permission for the file. You can now get access to it.

Comment: Please also add information of how you installed sphinx, which version of windows, python and perl you are using. What setup you did before running the command `sphinxtrain run`

Comment: I have downloaded sphinx [here](https://github.com/arafat3341/Speech-Recognizer-for-other-language) and followed the steps.  I am using Windows 10.  I am using python 3.9.1 and ActivePerl (perl 5 version 28 subversion 1).  So, before running the command `python ../sphinxtrain/scripts/sphinxtrain run`, i ran the command `python ../sphinxtrain/scripts/sphinxtrain -t other setup`